# Mysql query with count Resource id #11

Tags: php, mysql

MyCode

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`op_id`) FROM `room_group_options` WHERE `group` = '$group'");
echo $query;
$result = mysql_result($query, 0) ==  1) ? true : false;
if($result === true)
{
$error = 'already have this data';
}
```

My code for checking already have data yet?, the problem is after run this code is the result always false, then I have try to echo $query and I got Resource id #11

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query` return a  [`resource`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php)

and also change the condition as [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) return **false** on failure

so condition should be like this

```
$result = (FALSE !== mysql_result($query, 0)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

if you want to fetch from resource link so call

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $fetch[]= $row;
}
```

Comment: This is interesting `(false != ...)`

Comment: this is better way to avoid mistake of assigning  variable in `if`

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this to determine the result of `mysql_result()`

```
echo "<pre>",print_r(mysql_result($query, 0) , TRUE),"</pre>";
```

but it seems you have an unpaired starting parenthesis in here

```
$result = mysql_result($query, 0) ==  1) ? true : false;
```

should be, i assume

```
$result = (mysql_result($query, 0) ==  1) ? true : false;
```